# Add class to direct descendent ul element

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class to **only** the first ul.navigation__nav__submenu and not the second level ul.navigation__nav__submenu. How can I do this?
My html code is:

```
<ul class="navigation__nav__list">
  <li>
    <a href="/" title="Products">Products</a>
    <ul class="navigation__nav__submenu">
      <li>
        <a href="/">Smart charging stations</a>
        <ul class="navigation__nav__submenu">
          <li>
            <a href="/">First</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/">Second</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I created a fiddle with an attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/ginalolli/t60rLcve/

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__nav__list > .navigation__nav__submenu')` will probably do the job

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but it did not add a class to any ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$('.navigation__nav__submenu:first').addClass('demo-only');
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/t60rLcve/1/

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer if this solved your problem